# How to access MySQL field names while reading records

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using this code to get data from a mysql database:

```
ResultSet rs= statement.executeQuery(" select id, email from table ");
System.out.println( rs.getInt(1) );
System.out.println( rs.getString(2) );
```

I want to access field names by their names instead of numerical values as shown above.
Is something like this possible/available:

```
rs.getValue("id");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `rs.getInt("id")` will work as you'd expect it to.

Also, see [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html).

Answer (score 0):

The method `getInt(String columnLabel)` in the `ResultSet` interface will accept a string with the column name, so in your case it will be `getInt("id");` and yes it will work.

Cheers.